# Measuring distribution of growth rates

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I have monthly sales data for 50,000 companies. Unfortunately, I have very limited statistics training.

I suspect/hope that by some measure of growth these companies would fit into a standard normal distribution, but I can't figure out what that measure would be. By default we measure growth as a ratio, e.g. monthly growth is

```
(this_months_sales / last_months_sales) - 1
```

But since sales are never negative, the range of this number is -1 to infinity. I can't take the log of this number, either, since it goes through zero.

I want to get a mean and standard deviation of growth so I can characterize relative performance consistently. I mean, how much harder is it to achieve 100x growth compared to 50x growth? Is that as hard as going from 1x growth to 2x growth?

How should I proceed?

Comment: Re logarithms: your expression is a good approximation of the log of the sales ratio whenever that ratio is close to $1$. You should therefore consider working with the log of the ratio itself. That is almost always a better way to express the ratios.

Comment: @whuber the challenge with using logs is that these are small startups, so a lot of the sales numbers are zero and a lot of them fluctuate wildly as a ratio, 100 one month, -100 the next month. I can't just throw this data out because it's a very large subset and I need to track the whole field.